# Como realizar moda estatística em SQL?

Tags: sql, firebird

Trabalho para uma empresa de sistema de tarifação telefônica, todas as ligações geradas pela central (PABX) são tarifadas pelo sistema e armazenadas em uma tabela chamada **cadcha**.

```
cadcha
------------------------------------------
nreg   | telefone | ramaldestino | teldata    | telpretot
1000     35420000   6050           03/08/2015   2,50
1001     35428790   6050           03/08/2015   1,20
1002     33590000   6050           03/08/2015   2,50
```

telpretot = valor da ligação.

Para fazer uma somatória, por exemplo, já tenho a seguinte consulta funcionando:

```
SELECT SUM(telpretot)
FROM cadcha
WHERE teldata = '08/03/2015' 
AND
ramaldestino = '6050';
```

Agora, gostaria de saber, como ficaria esta mesma query para calcular a moda estatística, ou seja, o valor que mais apareceu nos registros da tabela cadcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui realizar o calculo agrupando pelo valor e ordenando por ordem decrescente.

```
SELECT COUNT(telpretot) as qtde, telpretot
FROM cadcha
WHERE teldata = '08/03/2015'
GROUP BY telpretot
ORDER BY qtde DESC
```